# Direction parameter in knp paginator bundle doesn't seem to be respected by knp_pagination_sortable helper

Tags: symfony, twig, knppaginator

I'm facing the following issue:

In my project i use KNP Paginator Bundle 1.2.4. I have to generate separate links for ascending and descending sorting. It looks like this in my twig template:

```
{{ knp_pagination_sortable(houses, 'Personen: laag - hoog', 'h.maxNumberOfGuests', {'class': 'sortable'}, {'dir': 'asc'}, 'HouseSearchCoreBundle:Pagination:sortable_dropdown_li.html.twig') }}
{{ knp_pagination_sortable(houses, 'Personen: hoog - laag', 'h.maxNumberOfGuests', {'class': 'sortable'}, {'dir': 'desc'}, 'HouseSearchCoreBundle:Pagination:sortable_dropdown_li.html.twig') }}
```

The problem is that if I add any other value to the options array (containing 'dir' at the moment) - it would be respected in the URI that this method generates, but it doesn't respect 'dir', as it generates the standard links with automatically switching 'dir' option.

I did change the 'direction' parameter in my system configuration:

```
sort_direction_name: dir
```

I need links that won't change their 'dir' parameter after sorting.
Has anyone faced this issue before?

Code of the `HouseSearchCoreBundle:Pagination:sortable_dropdown_li.html.twig`:

```
<li>
    <a{% for attr, value in options %} {{ attr }}="{{ value }}"{% endfor %}>{{ title }}</a>
</li>
```